# Applying Itô formula to this SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the SDE
$$dX_t = (a+bX_t)dt +cX_t dB_t,$$ where $B_t$ is Brownian motion, and $a,b,c >0$.
The solution should be
$$X_t = e^{(-\frac{1}{2}c^2+b)t+cB_t}[X_0 + a \int_0^t e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)s-cB_s} ds].$$

I try to apply Itô formula to
$$g = e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t}X_t,$$ but I get a different solution.

I have: $\frac{dg}{dt} = (\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)g~$ and $~\frac{dg}{dX_t} = e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t}$.
Then
$$d e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t}X_t = \frac{dg}{dt} dt + \frac{dg}{dX_t} dX_t.$$
But should I apply stochastic product rule to $d e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t}X_t$?
I think so, then I get:
$$d e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t}X_t + e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t}dX_t = (\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t}X_t dt + e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t} dX_t.$$
Which yields to:
$$d e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t}X_t  = (\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t}X_t dt.$$

But now the coefficient $a$ does not occur before integral. So where I make mistakes?

Comment: Write $g_t=Y_tX_t$ with $Y_t=e^{(\frac{1}{2}c^2-b)t-cB_t}$. What you need to apply is the integration-by-parts formula: $dg_t=X_t\,dY_t+Y_t\,dX_t+\color{red}{d\langle X,Y\rangle_t}\,.$